# How to add multiple fields in 'lookup_field'?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model which has 2 fields that will always be unique.
I want to add them both to the 'lookup_field' attribute

Models.py:

```
id=models.Integerfield()
slug=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
```

Serializer.py:

```
id=serializers.IntegerField()
slug=serializers.CharField()
class Meta:
   model=model
   fields=['id','slug']
```

Views.py:

```
class ExampleView(generics.RetrieveUpdateView):
      queryset=JobCategories.objects.all()
      serializer_class=JobCategorySerializer
      lookup_fields=('id',slug')
```

Comment: You can't add multiple `lookup_fields` in viewset.

Comment: Any other alternative to add multiple fields except adding another endpoint?